# Yii. Какой учший способ добавления функций к моделям?

Tags: activerecord, model, php, yii, база-данных

Привет всем!
Есть довольно много моделей, порядка 25 штук. База структура таблиц иногда меняется, и генерация обновленной модели по БД превращается в АД. Ну, в смысле, нужно убедиться, что все функции скопировал во временный файлик, перегенерировал файл с моделью, вставил обратно функции.

Что-то мне подсказывает, что этот подход неправильный, и есть более красивые способы решения этой задачи.

Кто нибудь может мне помочь с этим?

Comment: [миграции.][1]


  [1]: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/database.migration

Comment: Думаете по этой теме вопрос? У меня ощущение, что неправильно организована иерархия моделей.

Comment: Иерархия правильная, просто мне кажется, что можно каким то образом избавиться кастомной логики в моделях, к примеру, вынеся их в поведения. Проблема в том, что Я не знаю, как это сделать XD

Comment: @nolka - я именно это вам и показал в [коде][1], вы создаете интерфейс модели, перечисляя там методы, которые точно должны быть в модели. Так же вы создаете класс некой сущности модели, где реализуете все побочные методы. Сам класс модели, наследуется от этой сущности (extends EntityModel), и реализуете интерфейс модели (implements IModel) тем самым обезопасите себя от забывания реализации каких-либо методов, вам об этом скажет интерпретатор при запуске, если вы не реализуете какой либо из методов объявленных в интерфейсе. 

[1]: http://ideone.com/DJY2FE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пользуетесь каким-то кодогенератором?

Посмотрите этот [код](http://ideone.com/DJY2FE), возможно он натолкнет вас на какие нибудь мысли.

Comment: Да, Я пользуюсь #gii

Comment: @nolka - а почему вы не можете редактировать модели в ручную? зачем при изменении структуры, заново генерировать модель с нуля, когда в ней уже лежит куча кода. Ну да, это сущий ад, делать так каждый раз.

P.S.: какой IDE вы пользуетесь?

Comment: @ua6xh, Я привык структуру БД дизайнерить в Mysql workbench в случае м mysql, или pgadmin в случае с postgres. Это плохая привычка?)

Comment: @nolka - не знаю, я из консоли работаю =)
Если вам часто приходится менять структуру БД, может быть вы её неправильно проектируете? Наша компания ведет проект c 50+ таблицами, и при этом у нас поля редактируются очень редко. В основном бд не меняется, за исключение добавления новых сущностей.

Comment: @ua6xh. Проект начат только недавно) Просто иногда отказываюсь от тех или иных полей в БД.

Comment: Так вы продумайте БД изначально, нормализуйте её, посмотрите как тот или иной компонент системы будет с ней взаимодействовать, накидайте инфологическую модель. Проблема не в том, что вы попадаете в ад при пересоздании модели, а в том - что какой-то другой фактор заставляет делать вас это снова и снова. Возможно, если это было бы всего пару раз - вы бы не придали этому значения =)

Comment: Извините что врываюсь в тред, но я обычно изменения в модель вношу ручками, при добавлении нескольких колонок и связей, это занимает несколько минут времени.

Answer (score 0):

Вы смотрите на проблему под неправильным углом: вам нужны тесты, именно через них вы можете оперативно увидеть, что сломалось при изменении того или иного кода или структуры хранения данных.